# Rewire : How to access an exported class and a function and test them?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, rewire

I have a class and a function in one file

```
export class MainClass{
....
}

export function test_function(){}
```

Previously, I just had the `test_function` exported and could easily test it using

```
 rewire('file.ts').__get__("test_function")
```

How can I access the class to test its functions? (Preferably not moving the class to another file)